# Selected Value in dropdown should not be repeated

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my database field.

```
    cat_id | cat_name   | parent    | parent_id
-----------------------------------------------
    1      | Electronics| --        | 0

    2      | Apparels   |--         |0

    3      | Mens       | Apparels  |2
```

Here is my database structure, Now I am developing some basic CRUD operations where if admin wants to edit category he can, so when he edit the selected category name should be shown in dropdown and also other options if he want to change then he can. I am getting the repeated category name here I show you.

Here is my fields:

```
Category Name: Mens
Dropdown Menu: --Root Level--
               Apparels(Selected Value)
               Electronics
               Apparels
                --Mens
```

This was design structure. Here is my php code:

```
<tr>
                <td><h4>Update category</h4></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><?php $result=mysql_query("SELECT * from category Where cat_id='$id'");
                            $row=mysql_fetch_array($result)?><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row["cat_name"]; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <?php 
                      function fetchCategoryTree($parent = 0, $spacing = '', $user_tree_array = '') {

                        if (!is_array($user_tree_array))
                          $user_tree_array = array();

                        $sql = "SELECT `cat_id`, `cat_name`, `parent_id` FROM `category` WHERE 1 AND `parent_id` = $parent ORDER BY cat_id ASC";
                        $query = mysql_query($sql);
                        if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
                          while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
                            $user_tree_array[] = array("id" => $row->cat_id, "name" => $spacing . $row->cat_name);
                            $user_tree_array = fetchCategoryTree($row->cat_id, $spacing . '&nbsp;->', $user_tree_array);
                          }
                        }
                        return $user_tree_array;
                      }?>

                      <?php 
                      $categoryList = fetchCategoryTree();
                      ?>
                <td> Category:</td><td><select name="parentcat" id="parentcat" onchange="getText(this)">
                <option value="Root">--Root Level--</option>
                <option selected value="<?php echo $row["parent_id"];?>"><?php echo $row["parent"];?></option>
                  <?php foreach($categoryList as $cl) { 
                        ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $cl["id"] ?>"><?php echo $cl["name"]; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                  </select>
                    <input type="hidden" id="catnamehidden" name="hdnCatname">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are calling $categoryList = fetchCategoryTree(); this you are not passing parent category id that is why it is giving you all the category starting from the parent 0 and so you are getting repeating values. Try passing parent id in that function like this.

```
$categoryList = fetchCategoryTree($row["parent_id"],$spacing = '', $user_tree_array = '');
```